# .NET 4.7.2 => c-sharp => UI async/await

Tags: multithreading, async-await

I'm trying to load a content of a text file into text box asynchronously.
Therefore my goal is to not block the UI-Thread.
To check that, the code gives feedback with Console.Writeline("..."+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)

My first intention shows the code below, which will give me Thread 1 in both Console.WriteLines().
That means UI-Thread is blocked, right?

```
    private async void cmdProgrammLaden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button-Thread-ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        this.txtSendData.Text = await DncProgrammLadenAsync();
    }

    async Task<string> DncProgrammLadenAsync()
    {
        string path     = String.Empty;
        string content  = String.Empty;

        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"c:\Test\";
            openFileDialog.Filter           = "Textfile (*.txt)|*.txt";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex      = 0;
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = openFileDialog.FileName;
                var filestream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filestream))
                {
                    content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Task-Thread-ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    //Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
            }
            return content;

        }

    }
```

```
Then I tried to rework this code like *(short version)*
```

```
          Task.Run(() =>
            {
                string content = String.Empty;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\Test\File C.txt"))
                {
                    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine("Task-Thread-ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                }
                
            });
```

```
Then I get different Thread IDs.
But this seems not right to me.

What do I not understand correctly?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That means UI-Thread is blocked, right?

No. [By default, `await` captures the current context and resumes executing the `async` method in that context when that `await` completes](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). The UI thread is not blocked during the `await`, but the code resumes executing on the UI thread *after* the `await`.

However, file streams are tricky. They are only asynchronous if opened with an asynchronous flag, and I have no idea if `OpenFile` passes that flag. Asynchronous APIs called on a synchronous file handle just run the operation on a thread pool thread (I think).